# Universal Links opened in unsupported apps, are they completely lost?

Tags: ios, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I am trying to implement Branch marketing links in my app. I want for example to be able to create a link to share with users that will route them to a particular screen in the app. I noticed from the Branch docs that for some apps the link just opens the app store and not the actual app (even if it is installed). Being based in Asia I have the feeling that most of our customers will be wanting to share the link via an unsupported app such as Line. If a user is redirected to the app store via the link and then taps “open app”,  what happens? Is the link meta data lost? Does the meta data only remain if the link is opened in an app such as mail or notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here:

[This list](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#appsbrowsers-that-support-universal-links) in the Branch documentation gives a partial list of apps that support Universal Links, but unfortunately it is not complete. We've tried to cover the most common apps.

Line is using a custom webview (not `SFSafariViewController`). It doesn't support Universal Links for the initial click, but this is one of the edge cases where Branch can detect the originating app and do some custom behavior. For Line, we trigger your app's URI scheme. This means the behavior your users see when clicking a Branch link from within Line is the same as Universal Links, even though Universal Links isn't actually the protocol being used.

If you want to handle other apps where Branch doesn't have a workaround like this, you could try enabling the [deepviews feature](https://dev.branch.io/features/deepviews/overview/). This will cause the link to open a content preview with a button to launch the app (or forward to the App Store if not installed).

When a user with the app already installed clicks the **Open** button on the App Store page, *all the meta data is preserved and they will still be deep linked*. Branch doesn't know (or care!) what happens between when the user clicks the link and the app launches, so that gives you plenty of flexibility.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Exactly what I was looking for. I think I will use the Deep Views feature so I won't run into any issues with Facebook. I also noticed that Deep Views worked fine with Line.

Answer (score 0):

Universal Links have [some restrictions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) - not from Branch but from Apple's implementation. One of these restrictions is Universal Links cannot be opened from `SFSafariViewController`.

From [Branch's docs](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#appsbrowsers-that-support-universal-links), Line is not explicitly mentioned but other popular messaging apps may be of interest. I don't have Line myself but whether Line launches websites in it's own browser or the Safari app may give you a clue.

> Facebook Messenger -  works conditionally
>
> WeChat -  works conditionally
>
> Twitter - works conditionally
>
> LinkedIn -    works conditionally
>
> Any app using SFSafariViewController -    works conditionally

Comment: If the App Store is launched instead of the app (i.e. it isn't supported) does the meta data still get passed through when open app is tapped?

Comment: Oh it seems I misunderstood - you're wondering if the statistics will still be logged? Perhaps I will delete my answer if that is the case.

Comment: (Branch team member here) @bradkratky your answer is accurate — no need to delete!